# Alias a cmd in bash, without editing the script

Tags: bash, sh

Consider the following script

```
#!/bin/bash
abc
```

Here I want the "abc" cmd to be aliased to echo "Hi"(say) 
But I don't have control to modify the script.

Is there a way to make the cmd behavior change without touching the script?

Comment: Is abc an external command used in the script, or is it a function call?

Comment: The only way to make `abc` in the script `echo "Hi"` would be to create an alias in your shell environment through your `.bashrc` file. E.g. `alias abc='echo "Hi"'` in your `.bashrc` would make your script output `"Hi"`.

Comment: abc is an external cmd @jordanm

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin that's not true unless the script already contains `shopt -s expand_aliases`

Comment: @SatyaTeja add a new script named abc in a directory in higher precedence in your PATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
$ cat ./someScript.sh
#!/bin/bash
abc

$ ./someScript.sh
./someScript.sh: line 2: abc: command not found
```

Define a function named `abc`, and **export** it.

```sh
$ abc() { echo Hi; }
$ export -f abc
```

Now:

```sh
$ ./someScript.sh
Hi
```